# Multiple discounts on same product

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a query to return the discounted amount for each discount coupon but wanted to see if there are better way to handle this. Is there a way to handle it without using loop? I am a bit concerned that the query would run slow when retrieving a large data set.

Logic

1. percentage discount should be applied first before applying any currency discount
   (if multiple percentage discount applied, the discount should be applied based on the order they are added)
   for example, 10% discount applied -> 20% discount applied -> $5 discount applied
2. the second discount is applied to the net price AFTER the first discount has been taken
   the third  discount is applied to the net price AFTER the second discount has been taken

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Discounts 
    
    CREATE TABLE #Discounts 
    (
        ID                  INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
        ,[type]             VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
        ,[value]            DECIMAL(15,2) NOT NULL
        ,[totalValue]       DECIMAL(15,2) NOT NULL
        ,discountValue      DECIMAL(15,2) NULL
    )
    
    INSERT #Discounts ([type], [value], [totalValue]) VALUES ('percentage', 10, 100)
    INSERT #Discounts ([type], [value], [totalValue]) VALUES ('currency', 5, 100)
    INSERT #Discounts ([type], [value], [totalValue]) VALUES ('percentage', 20, 100)
    
    --sequenceNbr: the order of discount applied
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Discounts_Temp
    
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [type] DESC, ID) AS sequenceNbr
        INTO #Discounts_Temp
    FROM #Discounts
    
    DECLARE @int TINYINT, @pdiscount DECIMAL(15,2)
    
    SET @int = 1
    SET @pdiscount = NULL
    
    WHILE (@int <= (SELECT MAX(sequenceNbr) FROM #Discounts_Temp))
    BEGIN
    
        
        UPDATE t
            SET discountValue = IIF(type='percentage',(IIF(@pdiscount IS NOT NULL,@pdiscount,[totalValue])) * ([value]/100.0),[value])
        FROM #Discounts_Temp t
        WHERE sequenceNbr = @int
    
        SELECT @pdiscount = IIF(@pdiscount IS NOT NULL, @pdiscount, totalValue) - discountValue FROM #Discounts_Temp WHERE sequenceNbr = @int
        
        SET @int = @int + 1
        SET @pdiscount = @pdiscount
    END
    
    SELECT * FROM #Discounts_Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

We actually needed a little more DDL/DML in order to set up a demo.

```
DECLARE @Discounts TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, type VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, value DECIMAL(15,2) NOT NULL, totalValue DECIMAL(15,2) NOT NULL, discountValue DECIMAL(15,2) NULL)
INSERT INTO @Discounts (type, value, totalValue) VALUES 
('percentage', 10, 100),('currency', 5, 100), ('percentage', 20, 100)

DECLARE @OrderDiscounts TABLE (OrderID INT, DiscountID INT)
DECLARE @Orders TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, Amount DECIMAL(10,2))

INSERT INTO @Orders (Amount) VALUES 
(200.00),(2000.00)

INSERT INTO @OrderDiscounts (OrderID, DiscountID) VALUES
(1,1),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2)
```

I've added an Orders table and a OrderDiscounts table, so we have some orders to play with. I also switch to using Table Variables as there's less to clean up afterwards, but that's just a personal preference.

In a situation like this, where your row is going to be dependent on the previous row there's likely going to be some level of recursion going on. In this example we're going to use a recursive CTE (Common Table Expression) to do the dirty work for us.

```
;WITH base AS (
SELECT OrderID, a.DiscountID, a.DiscountValue, a.DiscountType, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.orderID ORDER BY a.DiscountType DESC, DiscountID) AS DiscountSeq, Amount
  FROM (
SELECT o.ID AS orderID, d.ID AS DiscountID, d.Value AS DiscountValue, d.Type AS DiscountType, o.Amount 
  FROM @Orders o                                                                            
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @OrderDiscounts od                                                      
      ON o.ID = od.OrderID                                                                  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Discounts d                                                            
      ON od.DiscountID = d.ID                                                               
 WHERE type = 'percentage'                                                                                                                                                  
UNION ALL                                                                                   
SELECT o.ID AS orderID, d.ID AS DiscountID, d.Value AS DiscountValue, d.Type AS DiscountType, o.Amount
  FROM @Orders o
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @OrderDiscounts od
      ON o.ID = od.OrderID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Discounts d
      ON od.DiscountID = d.ID
 WHERE type = 'currency'
     ) a
), rCTE AS (
SELECT OrderID, DiscountID, DiscountValue, DiscountType, DiscountSeq, Amount, 
CAST(CASE WHEN DiscountType = 'percentage' THEN Amount *(DiscountValue/100.0) WHEN DiscountType = 'currency' THEN DiscountValue END AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS DiscountAmount,
CAST(Amount - CASE WHEN DiscountType = 'percentage' THEN Amount *(DiscountValue/100.0) WHEN DiscountType = 'currency' THEN DiscountValue END AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS NewAmount 
  FROM base 
 WHERE DiscountSeq = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT a.OrderID, r.DiscountID, r.DiscountValue, r.DiscountType, r.DiscountSeq, CAST(0.00 AS DECIMAL(10,2)),
CAST(CASE WHEN r.DiscountType = 'percentage' THEN NewAmount *(r.DiscountValue/100.0) WHEN r.DiscountType = 'currency' THEN r.DiscountValue END AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS DiscountAmount,
CAST(a.NewAmount - CASE WHEN r.DiscountType = 'percentage' THEN a.NewAmount *(r.DiscountValue/100.0) WHEN r.DiscountType = 'currency' THEN r.DiscountValue END AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS NewAmount 
  FROM rCTE a
    INNER JOIN base r
      ON a.orderID = r.orderID
      AND a.DiscountSeq + 1 = r.DiscountSeq
)

SELECT OrderID, DiscountID, DiscountValue, DiscountType, DiscountAmount,
SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS TotalBeforeDiscount, 
SUM(DiscountAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS TotalDiscount,
SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY (SELECT 1))-SUM(DiscountAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS TotalAfterDiscount
  FROM rCTE
```

| OrderID | DiscountID | DiscountValue | DiscountType | DiscountAmount | TotalBeforeDiscount | TotalDiscount | TotalAfterDiscoun |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10.00 | percentage | 20.00 | 200.00 | 56.00 | 144.00 |
| 1 | 3 | 20.00 | percentage | 36.00 | 200.00 | 56.00 | 144.00 |
| 2 | 1 | 10.00 | percentage | 200.00 | 2000.00 | 205.00 | 1795.00 |
| 2 | 2 | 5.00 | currency | 5.00 | 2000.00 | 205.00 | 1795.00 |

I think this is the output you were looking to achieve, but what's going on here?

First we use a `CTE` to get a base line look at all the data. You wanted to make sure the discounts where applied in order, all we really have to order them by is the `ID`, so we've used that. If you had a sequence column in the `OrderDiscounts` table to tell us which order to apply them for the particular order, we could use that instead. We've split up the types between percentages and currencies as you asked, and we'll take care of processing the percentages first, but you can change that by modifying how `DiscountSeq` is ordered.

Using this base we build the `rCTE` to iterate over each of the orders by fetching the first discount for each order, we can find it by looking for `DiscountSeq` 1

Now for the magic part. We're going to join back to the base for the next `DiscountSeq` for this `OrderID`. We can now use both sets of rows (the previous and this one) to figure out what the current amount is, and how much we want to apply, in the case of a percentage discount.

Selecting from the `rCTE` gives us a row, per discount applied, tells us what type it was and what the discount amount applied is. Since we now know all that we have have a little `windowed function` fun and also display the totals for the whole order as well.

Hope this gets you going in the right direction for your ultimate goal!

Comment: Thanks, Patrick. I really appreciate your help on this. Got everything working fine now. Thanks!